# Last Modified File in Python?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write a script that allows me import the most recently modified file from a directory.  I've looked at the `glob` and `os.listdir` commands but they don't seem to do it (I get errors). Any thoughts?

```
import os
import glob
newest = max(glob.iglob('Directory Name'), key=os.path.getctime)
print newest
f = open(newest,'r')
```

I get an error:

> max() arg is an empty sequence

Would something like os.stat work better?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: As error says - glob.iglob returns an empty sequence. Maximal value from empty sequence is unknown. Therefore exception is raised.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted a `/*` at the end of that glob?

Comment: At the end of the *glob*, not the end of the line of code.  Put it right after `Directory Name`, before the closing quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
newest = max(glob.iglob('Directory Name/*'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: @champ8686: Is the directory empty?  Did you spell its name right?

Comment: I got it.  Thanks guys!  The /* was needed.